# Terraforms remote-exec on each host created

Tags: terraform

I am trying to set up a group of EC2s for an app using Terraform in AWS. After each server is created I want to mount the eNVM instance storage on each server using remote-exec. So create 3 servers and then mount the eNVM on each of the 3 servers

attempted to use null_resource but I am getting errors about 'resource depends on non-existent resource' or 'interpolation' errors

```
variable count {
  default = 3
}

module "app-data-node" {
  source           = "some_git_source"
  count            = "${var.count}"
  instance_size    = "instance_data"
  hostname_pattern = "app-data"
  dns_domain       = "${data.terraform_remote_state.network.dns_domain}"
  key_name         = "app-automation"
  description      = "Automation App Data Instance"
  package_proxy    = "${var.package_proxy}"
}

resource "null_resource" "mount_envm" {
  # Only run this provisioner for app nodes
  #count = "${var.count}"

  depends_on = [
    "null_resource.${module.app-data-node}"
  ]

  connection {
  host        = "${aws_instance.i.*.private_ip[count.index]}"
  user        = "root"
  private_key = "app-automation"
}

provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1",
    "sudo mkdir /data",
    "sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1 /data"
  ]
 }
}
```

3 EC2 instances each with eNVMs mounted on them.

Comment: The `provisioner` is supposed to be inside the `aws_instance` resource, but really what you are doing in that provisioner would be best practices with Packer instead anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `null_resource` to run the provisioner:

```
resource "null_resource" "provisioner" {
  count = "${var.count}"

  triggers {
    master_id = "${element(aws_instance.my_instances.*.id, count.index)}"
  }

  connection {
    #host        = "${element(aws_instance.my_instances.*.private_ip, count.index)}"
    host        = "${element(aws_instance.my_instances.*.private_ip, count.index)}"
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "..."
    private_key = "..."
  }

  # set hostname
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1",
      "sudo mkdir /data",
      "sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1 /data"
    ]
  }
}
```

This should do it for all instances at once as well.

Comment: this should be marked as answer, as it works like a charm